# 'von einer' meaning 'ist'?

Tags: meaning

I have [come across](https://de.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europ%C3%A4isches_Nordmeer) this passage:

> Der Meeresgrund ist **von einer** sehr unebenen Bodengestalt und reich an
> Erdgas und -öl, die Küstenzonen dienen zahlreichen Fischen des
> Nordatlantiks als Laichgebiet.

What does *von einer* mean here? The only translation I can think of is: "The ocean floor is very uneven".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expression is "von einer Gestalt sein" - which literally translates to

> The ocean floor *is of a very uneven shape*.